# install postgres 9.4 on ubuntu 14.04-2

Tags: apt, software-installation, postgresql

I need to install **postgresql** 9.4 server but I only can find version 9.3. wit apt.

How can I install or upgrade it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Install with the steps below and read the statement at the end of this answer.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

> The PostgreSQL Global Development Group (PGDG) maintains an APT
>   repository of PostgreSQL packages for Debian and Ubuntu located at
>   http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/. We aim at building
>   PostgreSQL server packages as well as extensions and modules packages
>   on several Debian/Ubuntu releases for all PostgreSQL versions
>   supported.
>
> Currently, we support
>
> - Debian 6 (squeeze), 7 (wheezy), 8 (jessie) and unstable (sid) 64/32 bit (amd64/i386)
> - Ubuntu 12.04 (precise), 14.04 (trusty), 14.10 (utopic) 64/32 bit (amd64/i386)
> - PostgreSQL 8.4, 9.0, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4
> - Server extensions such as Slony-I, various PL languages, and datatypes
> - Applications like pgadmin3, pgbouncer, and pgpool-II
>
> Packages for older PostgreSQL versions and older Debian/Ubuntu
>   distributions will continue to stay in the repository; updates for
>   those will be provided on an ad-hoc basis.

<sub>[Source](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt)</sub>

Comment: The four lines above do not install postgresql.

Answer (score 5):

Below are steps to install PostgreSQL 9.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.

**[Reference taken from this Article:](http://www.dbrnd.com/2016/04/postgresql-how-to-install-postgresql-9-4-on-ubuntu-14-04/)**

**First, check the version of Ubuntu:**

```
lsb_release -sc
```

**You need to add the latest PostgreSQL repository for the latest version, otherwise It will install PostgreSQL 9.3. This is for trusty version.**

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main"
```

**Update and Install PostgreSQL 9.4:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4
```

**Default postgres super user and postgres database is created. You need to set a password for the postgres super user.**

```
ubuntu@:~$ sudo passwd postgres
Enter new UNIX password:****
Retype new UNIX password:****
passwd: password updated successfully
```

**If service is not started, you can start the PostgreSQL service.**

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

**Connect PostgreSQL server using postgres user:**

```
ubuntu@:~$ su postgres
Password:****
```

**Create a sample database:**

```
createdb database_name
```

**Connect to that database:**

```
psql -d database_name
```

Comment: You are the man

Answer (score 0):

postgresql-9.4 is not available in [14.04 "Trusty"](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/database/).  It was added in [14.10 "Utopic"](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/database/).

The directions on the [PostgreSQL Ubuntu Download page](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) shows some info.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to install software that you can not find in the official Ubuntu repositories search the web for a "PPA".

In your case I searched for "Postgresql 9.4 PPA" and found [this](http://media-opensource.blogspot.de/2015/02/postgresql-941-released-install-on.html) link.

Comment: This PPA is deprecated: https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/ubuntu/postgresql